# Tensorflow object detection API: How to disable loading from checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have created a custom variation of MobileNetV2 feature extractor architecture, by changing the `expansion_size` from 6 to 4 in `research/slim/nets/mobilenet/mobilenet_v2.py` of `tensorflow/models` repo.

I want to be able to train the SSD + Mobilenet_v2 (with this change) model with `model_main.py` script as described at Object Detection API's [running_locally tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md.).

When I do so I see the following error, which makes sense:

```
`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint.
```

To address this:

1. I removed the `finetune_checkpoint` specification from my `pipeline.config`.
2. I changed `load_pretrained=True` to `load_pretrained=False` in `object_detection/model_hparams.py`.
3. I added `--hparams_overrides='load_pretrained=false'` as a command line input argument to `model_main.py`.

Despite of these, I still see the same error.

Why is tensorflow still trying to restore a checkpoint. How can I make it not do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself. It turns out that even though I had made arrangements for it to not restore checkpoint from my pipeline configuration file, it turns out that the internal `tf.Estimator` object can still use a checkpoint from the `model_dir` specified; even though the primary use of `model_dir` is as an output directory, where output checkpoints are written to.

I found this information in the [official documentation for tf.Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator). Here's the relevant excerpt for reference:

> `model_dir: Directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. **This can also be used to load checkpoints from the directory into an estimator to continue training a previously saved model**. If PathLike object, the path will be resolved. If None, the model_dir in config will be used if set. If both are set, they must be same. If both are None, a temporary directory will be used.

I had an old checkpoint sitting in my original `model_dir` which was architecturally incompatible with my custom model. Hence I was seeing the error. To resolve it, I simply changed my `model_dir` to point to a new empty directory and it worked. I hope that helps someone with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks @bappak. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is wrong. This behaviour is not clarified in the TFOD API which I believe will cause a lot of people to stumble into this issue wondering what happened.